# How to validate input field for sorting against corresponding JSON properties of entity object

Tags: java, sorting, spring-data, entity

I need to validate user input field for sorting a API response against relevant entity / domain object to ensure that input JSON field name maps to a relevant field in entity object. If it does not map throw an exception.

I am currently using Spring data with spring boot where The API's are passed Pageable object. I need to validate that 'sort' property of Pageable object and validate against JSON property name of the corresponding fields in the entity object.

The solution needs to be generic so that I can scan user input for sort field(s) against the corresponding the JSON property of the each fields of Entity object. If there is no match then throw relevant error messages like 'Invalid Sort field'